# Images are too large

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have two images, one is a transparent TestTube.png (25 Width, 150 Height) and the other image is a Block.png (10 Width, 10 Height) that goes on "inside" of the test tube image.

Below is what I WANT my Screen View to look like, these would be just two different PNG's on top of each other a bunch of times.

```
|X| |X| |X|
|X| |X| |X|
|X| |X| |X|

|X| |X| |X|
|X| |X| |X|
|X| |X| |X|
```

And this is roughly what it looks like now

```
 | |    | |
XXXXX  XXXXX
XXXXX  XXXXX
XXXXX  XXXXX
 | |    | |
```

The Block.png is WAY too large, and I'm not sure how to make it smaller. Putting in a smaller image size does not seem to work.

I'm trying to use Grids to do this but I'm not sure if this is necessary or not.

```
function void doStuff()
{
   StackLayout objLayout = new StackLayout();
   Grid objGrid = new Grid();

   //Assign the grid layout two Rows and two Columns

   //Semi Psuedo Code
  foreach(column in grid)
  {
     TestTubeImage = new Image { Source = "tube.png", WidthRequest = 25, HeightRequest = 150 }; }
     BlockImage = new Image { Source = "block.png", WidthRequest = 10, HeightRequest = 10 }; }
     objGrid.Children.Add(TestTubeImage, x, y);
     objGrid.Children.Add(BlockImage, x, y);
  }

  objLayout.Children.Add(objGrid);
  Content = objLayout;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share us more code in the doStuff? How do you layout the row and column in Grid?

Comment: use the Image Aspect property